# passing javascript variables to html5 video tag using it as src for the player

Tags: javascript, html, flash, variables, video

I'm tryng to convert a webpage which use a flash video player to html5 `<video`> tag. This page use JS code to read the link of the file passing it to the flash player trought flashvars, the code is this

```
function justplay(link, title){
var playerobj = '<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" id="mainflashplayer" width="640" height="360"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />       <param name="flashvars" value="file=' + link + '" />        <param name="wmode" value="direct" />   <param name="movie" value="' + playerurl + '" /><param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always"><embed name="mainflashplayer" src="' + playerurl + '" AllowScriptAccess="always" wmode="direct" **flashvars="file=' + link + '"** width="640" height="360" allowFullScreen="true" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" /></object>';
                document.getElementById('player').innerHTML = playerobj;
                document.getElementById('playcontenttitle').innerHTML = title;
}
```

So, i'm tryng to pass `file=' + link + '` to `<video>` tag using it as a src. In wich way can I do that?

Comment: in a more general view. There is a variable called link which is used in the flash video player. I just want to replace the flash player with a html5 based one, so use the link variables as a source for the new player

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what it is that you want but if you want to use the html video tag than you can use the following to accomplish what you want.

```js
$(function() {
  justPlay('http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4', 'My video');
});
    
function justPlay(link, title){
  document.getElementById('player').setAttribute('src',link);
  document.getElementById('playcontenttitle').innerHTML = title;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="playcontenttitle"></p>
<video width="320" height="240" controls id="player">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: the first think I've tried to do is simply this 
` <video id="video" width="320" height="240" autoplay>
 <source src=" + link + ">
</video> `
but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you give me the link?